# Using FFmpegMediaPlayer - Apk size increased by 35MB approx - (without library apk size - 4mb)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer, media-player

Is there a workaround to this, as the size of the apk is drastically increased and the library was added through normal procedure -
 (compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaPlayer:1.0.4')

and not through manual inclusion or downloading I wonder whether anyone else has this problem.

Comment: use [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) and your app size will increase only ~ 1 MB, not 40

Comment: @pskink if you read the title, it says `apk size increased **to** 40MB`, not `by 40 MB`. If the APK was 39 MB before adding the library, that means either a different library or resources in the project itself take up most of the space

Comment: @pskink I'm sorry I edited the title its actually an incease by 39.48 MB to be approximate - The app size excluding FFMpg was 4mb - So a total of of around 35 mb increase

Comment: @pskink Yeah tried exoplayer even though it doesn't take up space. I still have to edit the coding drastically to attach it to an equalizer and am looking to see, is this normal for this dependency to take up so much space

Comment: @Zoe 40 MB or 35, whats the difference? what matters is `"the size of the apk is drastically increased"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you go to the source code of the library, to the releases page (https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer/releases) you'll see that you can manually download to your PC, what is normally being downloaded by gradle and then added to your APK.

There you can see it's 50mb zip, file so it's not crazy to imagine 35mb increase in the APK.

That's because it's not a half dozen Java files, like most libraries are, but this have the compiled binary code of the FFMPEG, compiled for each platform Android uses (arm, x86, 32 and 64bits).

So yeah, final conclusion, if you're really gonna use any ffmpeg based thing, your app will take this extra space.